# Python Selenium not taking me to instagram (Bot)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, bots, instagram

I'm really new to this so it's probably something really simple but this code wont even pick up going to instagram (I had it working up to searching for the hashtags but then i put them into defs as per a tutorial i was watching). I think i'm using the def functions wrong some how and that's why it isn't going anywhere.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
from time import sleep 


class instabot():
    def login(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[1]').click()
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input').send_keys(username)
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys(password)
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button').click()
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()
    #sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    def like_comment_hashtag(self, hashtags):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/" + random.choice(hashtags))
        sleep(random.randint(3,6))

        links = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        def condition(link):
            return '.com/p/' in link.get_attribute('href')
        valid_links = list(filter(condition, links))
    
        for i in range(5):
            link = valid_links[i].get_attribute('href')
            if link not in self.links:
                self.links.append(link) 
        for link in self.links:
            self.driver.get(link)
            sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button').click()
        sleep(5)
    #comment
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('RxpZH').click() 
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Add a comment…']").send_keys(random.choice(comments))
        sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems like you haven't actually initiated your class anywhere.
At the end of your code, add in:

```
instagrambot = instabot()
```

Also, within your class, your not running any of the functions.

Comment: okay, thank you for that, i'll add that in the end. How do I run the functions? (sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: after where you initiated your class, just do:
`instagrambot.functionname(whatever your parameters are)`
for all of the different functions.